# Fail to set value on azurerm_network_interface public_ip_address_id

Tags: azure, terraform

I’m new to Azure Terraform and is having issues setting public_ip_address_id correctly on this part of azurerm_network_interface resource. Can I request for advice. Thanks!

I'm creating 8 interface and trying to bind public ip on the first 3 interfaces. tried using try function to return and set public_ip_id on the first 3 interfaces and set null on the rest of the interfaces

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "virtual_network_interfaces" {
  
  for_each = var.interfaces

   location            = var.location
   resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name 

   name = "${var.device_name}_${var.instance_type}_${var.site_name}_${each.value.name}_Interface"    
   enable_ip_forwarding = true
   enable_accelerated_networking = true
   
   ip_configuration {
      name                          = "${var.device_name}_${var.instance_type}_${var.site_name}_${each.value.name}_IP_Config"
      private_ip_address            = each.value.address_prefixes[0]
      private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"  

      # set Management interface as primary vNIC
      primary = each.value.name == "Management" ? true : false

      subnet_id = try(
         lookup(
            { for k, v in var.subnets : v.name => v.id },
               each.value.name, null
         ), null
       )

       public_ip_address_id = try(
         {
            for k1, v1 in var.public_ips :
              k1 => can(regex("${each.value.name}", v1.name)) ? v1.id : null
          },
           null)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to set values on azurerm_network_interface public_ip_address_id and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The current logic you're using to set `public_ip_address_id` is to iterate over `var.public_ips` and, for each public IP, check if the current NIC's name (from `var.interfaces`) matches the name of the public IP. If it does, set the `public_ip_address_id` to the ID of that public IP, otherwise set it to `null`.

The issue with this approach is that the logic will always return the ID of the last matched public IP (or `null` if no match was found). This isn't ideal because, if multiple public IPs match the NIC's name, only the last one will be set.

Moreover, the use of the `can(regex())` function here is not ideal. If you're trying to bind the first 3 interfaces to public IPs, a more deterministic approach is recommended.

I tried to achieve your requirement using my won configuration module changes which were mentioned as follows.

**My terraform configuration:**

##### main.tf:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "vksbl-vnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "vksbl-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  count               = 3
  name                = "vksbl-public-ip-${count.index}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "virtual_network_interfaces" {
  count = length(var.interfaces)

  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  
  name                = "${var.device_name}_${var.instance_type}_${var.site_name}_${var.interfaces[count.index].name}_Interface"
  enable_ip_forwarding          = true
  enable_accelerated_networking = true
   
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.device_name}_${var.instance_type}_${var.site_name}_${var.interfaces[count.index].name}_IP_Config"
    private_ip_address            = var.interfaces[count.index].address_prefixes[0]
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    primary                       = var.interfaces[count.index].name == "Management" ? true : false

    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.example.id

    # Bind the first 3 interfaces to public IPs
    public_ip_address_id = count.index < 3 ? azurerm_public_ip.example[count.index].id : null
  }
}
```

##### variable.tf:

```
variable "interfaces" {
  description = "List of interfaces"
  type        = list(object({
    name            = string
    address_prefixes = list(string)
  }))
  default = [
    {
      name            = "Interface1"
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.4"]
    },
    {
      name            = "Interface2"
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.5"]
    },
    {
      name            = "Interface3"
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.6"]
    },
    {
      name            = "Interface4"
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.7"]
    },
    {
      name            = "Interface5"
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.8"]
    },
    {
      name            = "Interface6"
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.9"]
    },
    {
      name            = "Interface7"
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.10"]
    },
    {
      name            = "Interface8"
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.11"]
    }
  ]
}

variable "location" {
  description = "Azure region/location"
  default     = "East US"
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "Name of the resource group"
  default     = "demorgvk"
}

variable "device_name" {
  description = "Device name"
  default     = "my-device"
}

variable "instance_type" {
  description = "Instance type"
  default     = "t2.micro"
}

variable "site_name" {
  description = "Site name"
  default     = "my-site"
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

This configuration creates a virtual network, a subnet, 3 public IPs, and 8 network interfaces. The first 3 of those interfaces will be bound to the public IPs, while the rest will not have public IPs.

Comment: Thanks Vinay for looking into this and sharing your code fix. A bit more info... You're right the interface names and public_ip names are not the same hence regex match. This provisioning code is used to bring up multiple virtual network elements of different device types so it needs to be more flexible. These devices are also being provisioned one resource group so naming needs to handled to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Yes, I agree @mtnbkr. By taking necessary precautions to avoid conflicts you can manage to achieve the configuration you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting try code block is returning map object, to prove this theory i did the changes below. Looks like try block is returning a map object. Any advise to revise/enhance this code block. thanks!

```
 public_ip_address_id = tostring( try(
     {
         for k1, v1 in var.public_ips :
            k1 => can(regex("${each.value.name}", v1.name)) ?
            v1.id : tostring("")
      },
      tostring("")))
```